# `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen when using Nokogiri to open site

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I created a CLI program that uses Scraper class to scrape site. I am Using Nokogiri and Open-URI. The error on top is popping up. I looked online and did not find help.

I made sure the site doesn't have typos.

from the CLI class I create a new Scraper class using the site as arg

```
class KefotoScraper::CLI

    attr_accessor :kefoto_scraper

      def initialize
      site = "https://www.kefotos.mx"
      @kefoto_scraper = Scraper.new(site)
      end
end
```

In Scraper I have the following code:

```
class Scraper

  attr_accessor :doc, :product_names, :site, :name, :link


  def initialize(site)
    @site = site
    @doc = doc
    @product_names = product_names
    @name = name
    @link = link
    @price_range = [].uniq
    scrape_product
  end

  def get_html
    @doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@site))
    @product_names = doc.css(".navbar-nav li")
    product_names
  end

  def scrape_product
    get_html.each {|product|
      @name = product.css("span").text
      plink = product.css("a").attr("href").text
      @link = "#{site}#{link}"
      link_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open(@link))
      pr = link_doc.scan(/[\$£](\d{1,3}(,\d{3})*(\.\d*)?)/)
      prices = pr_link.text
        prices.each {|price|
          if @price_range.include?(price[0]) == false
            @price_range << price[0]
            end
        }

      new_product = Products.new(@name, @price_range)
      puts new_product
  }
  end

end
```

I get the following error:

scraper.rb:18:in `initialize': No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - https://www.kefotos.mx (Errno::ENOENT)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`open` by default operates on local files, not URLs. That error means "I can't find a file on your hard drive named `https://www.kefotos.mx`".

You can let it work on URIs by requiring the `open-uri` library:

```
require 'open-uri'
```

This will make your code work, but it is a much better practice to use a proper HTTP client to read HTTP resources, as an attacker could potentially use an overloaded `open()` to access files on your machine's hard drive.

For example, if you were to use just net/http:

```
# At the top of your scraper.rb:
require 'net/http'

# Then, in your class:
link_doc = Nokogiri::HTML(Net::HTTP.get(URI(@link)))
```

Comment: hi!! Thank you for your response. I added "require 'net/http' '